# how to count the difference between the two time in php and show it

Tags: php, php-7, php-5.6, php-7.2

I need to show the difference between two times in PHP I use `strtotime()` function to convert my times to integer but my problem is the result not matched what I expected

```
<?php
$hour1 = '12:00:00';
$hour2 = '9:00:00';
$avg = strtotime($hour1) - strtotime($hour2);
$result = date('h:i:s', $avg); // result = 06:30:00 what I expected is 3:00:00
```

But the difference is 3:00:00 how to calculate this?

Comment: `strtotime()` and `date` don't seem to be the right tool for this job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) instances and use [`diff`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) function to get the difference between 2 times. You can then format them in hours,minutes and seconds.

```
<?php

$hour1 = '12:00:00';
$hour2 = '09:00:00';

$o1 = new DateTime($hour1);
$o2 = new DateTime($hour2);

$diff = $o1->diff($o2,true); // to make the difference to be always positive.

echo $diff->format('%H:%I:%S');
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/X41pv

Answer (score 0):

You can do that:

```
$hour1 = '12:00:00';
$hour2 =  date('h', strtotime('9:00:00')); 
$avg= date('h:i:s', strtotime($hour1. ' - '.$hour2.' hours') );
echo $avg; //3:00:00
```